# Black screen after boot

Tags: linux, gnome

when boot `kali linux 2` after boot i got black screen
.After got black screen i done this work...but don't get any result

** login with `Ctrl+Alt+f2`
1-remove and reinstall `gnome-session`

2-
`apt-get update
   apt-get upgrade`

3-reading `/var/log/Xorg.o.log`
Is there suggestion to solve this problem?
thanks in advance...

Comment: i didn't found any result in the log file..and I work with hp pavilion dv2000

Comment: From the console, when you have the prompt after `Ctrl+Alt+f2`, are you able to launch any graphic program (maybe `xlogo` or `startx`)? If yes can you  manually launch your [Display Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_%28program_type%29). Please [edit] your question with this information, it can help to find a solution.

Comment: `startx` command not found

Comment: is it problem with display?`nvidia`? @Hastur

Comment: Just a question or two :-) Is this a new installation of the operative system? Did you ever succeed to start a graphic program on that computer with kali? I suppose you missed to install some part of X (I suppose you need to (re)install, but try to be sure before). You may find interesting to read [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/162330/196535) and its links. Moreover the problem is that you have the black screen instead of... ? Which Display Manager?

Comment: To see if X works you can try to run some little program as `xlogo`,`xeyes`...